# Dependent dropdown-list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make depending dropdown list. Second list depends on the first one, but when I coded and used it, it shows all of the answers, like "depending" didn't even work. Like this :
[image]

```js
$(function() {
  var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $("#category2");
  $cat.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $subcat.val("");
    if (!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled", true);
    $subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-history">
    <span>
       <div class="form-label"><label for="employeeID">WPROWADŹ ID TAG</label></div>
       <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="text" name="employeeID" id="employee_input"></div>
    </span>
    <span>
       <div class="form-label"><label for="DzialID">Wybierz dział</label></div>
       <div class="form-smallmessage">
         <select name="category1" id="category1">
           <option value="">Wybierz Dział</option>
           <option value="Making_TP">Making Toothpaste</option>
           <option value="Making_MW">Making MouthWash</option>
           <option value="Finishing_HSL">Finishing HSL</option>
           <option value="Finishing_LSL">Finishing LSL</option>
           <option value="Finishing_MW">Finishing MouthWash</option>
           <option value="VI_TUBES">VI Tubes</option>
           <option value="VI_PRINTING">VI Printing</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    </span>

    <div class="form-label"><label for="LineID">Wybierz linie</label></div>
    <div class="form-smallmessage">
      <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
        <option value>Wybierz linie</option>
        <!-- Making_TP -->
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee1">Lee 1</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee2">Lee 2</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee3">Lee 3</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee4">Lee 4</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee5">Lee 5</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee6">Lee 6</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="lee7">Lee 7</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="ZOATEC">Zoatec</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee9">Lee 9</option>
        <!-- Making_MW -->
        <option rel="Making_MW" value="MW1">Making MW 1</option>
        <option rel="Making_MW" value="MW2">Making MW 2</option>

        <!-- Finishing_HSL -->
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL1">High Speed Line 1</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL2">High Speed Line 2</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL3">High Speed Line 3</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL4">High Speed Line 4</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL5">High Speed Line 5</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL6">High Speed Line 6</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL7">High Speed Line 7</option>
        <!-- Finishing_LSL -->
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLA">Low Speed Line A</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLC">Low Speed Line C</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLD">Low Speed Line D</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLE">Low Speed Line E</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLG">Low Speed Line G</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLH">Low Speed Line H</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLI">Low Speed Line I</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLJ">Low Speed Line J</option>
        <!-- Finishing_MW -->
        <option rel="Finishing_MW" value="MWFIN1">Mouthwash Finishing 1</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_MW" value="MWFIN2">Mouthwash Finishing 2</option>
        <!-- VI_TUBES -->
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA1">Aisa 1</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA2">Aisa 2</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA3">Aisa 3</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA4">Aisa 4</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA5">Aisa 5</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA6">Aisa 6</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA7">Aisa 7</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA8">Aisa 8</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA9">Aisa 9</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA10">Aisa 10</option>
        <!-- VI_PRINTING -->
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG1">KPG1</option>
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG2">KPG2</option>
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG3">KPG3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <span>
      <div class="form-label"><label for="MachineID">Nazwa Maszyny</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="text" name="MachineID" id="Machine_input">  </div>     
    </span>
    <span>           
      <div class="form-label"><label for="DateID">Data wystąpienia problemu</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="date" name="DateID" id="Date_input"></div>   
    </span>
    <span> 
      <div class="form-labelbig"><label for="ProblemID">Opisz problem</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><textarea id="text" name="ProblemID" id ="problem_input" rows="10" cols="22"></textarea></div>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="button" value="ZABLOKUJ" id="gobutton">
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see on the screen it should show only Lee1-9 instead of all answers..
Can you tell me what did I do wrong and how do I fix it? Its the first time I'm trying to do something like this.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the part where you call `.show()` on the options that need to be visible, you should also make sure that you call `.hide()` on the others...

So do this:

```
    $subcat.find("option").hide().filter("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
```

Applied here:

```js
$(function() {
  var $cat = $("#category1"),
    $subcat = $("#category2");
  $cat.on("change", function() {
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.val("").find("option").attr("style", "");
    if (!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled", true);
    $subcat.find("option").hide().filter("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-history">
    <span>
       <div class="form-label"><label for="employeeID">WPROWADŹ ID TAG</label></div>
       <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="text" name="employeeID" id="employee_input"></div>
    </span>
    <span>
       <div class="form-label"><label for="DzialID">Wybierz dział</label></div>
       <div class="form-smallmessage">
         <select name="category1" id="category1">
           <option value="">Wybierz Dział</option>
           <option value="Making_TP">Making Toothpaste</option>
           <option value="Making_MW">Making MouthWash</option>
           <option value="Finishing_HSL">Finishing HSL</option>
           <option value="Finishing_LSL">Finishing LSL</option>
           <option value="Finishing_MW">Finishing MouthWash</option>
           <option value="VI_TUBES">VI Tubes</option>
           <option value="VI_PRINTING">VI Printing</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    </span>

    <div class="form-label"><label for="LineID">Wybierz linie</label></div>
    <div class="form-smallmessage">
      <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
        <option value>Wybierz linie</option>
        <!-- Making_TP -->
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee1">Lee 1</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee2">Lee 2</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee3">Lee 3</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee4">Lee 4</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee5">Lee 5</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee6">Lee 6</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="lee7">Lee 7</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="ZOATEC">Zoatec</option>
        <option rel="Making_TP" value="Lee9">Lee 9</option>
        <!-- Making_MW -->
        <option rel="Making_MW" value="MW1">Making MW 1</option>
        <option rel="Making_MW" value="MW2">Making MW 2</option>

        <!-- Finishing_HSL -->
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL1">High Speed Line 1</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL2">High Speed Line 2</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL3">High Speed Line 3</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL4">High Speed Line 4</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL5">High Speed Line 5</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL6">High Speed Line 6</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_HSL" value="HSL7">High Speed Line 7</option>
        <!-- Finishing_LSL -->
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLA">Low Speed Line A</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLC">Low Speed Line C</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLD">Low Speed Line D</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLE">Low Speed Line E</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLG">Low Speed Line G</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLH">Low Speed Line H</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLI">Low Speed Line I</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_LSL" value="LSLJ">Low Speed Line J</option>
        <!-- Finishing_MW -->
        <option rel="Finishing_MW" value="MWFIN1">Mouthwash Finishing 1</option>
        <option rel="Finishing_MW" value="MWFIN2">Mouthwash Finishing 2</option>
        <!-- VI_TUBES -->
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA1">Aisa 1</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA2">Aisa 2</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA3">Aisa 3</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA4">Aisa 4</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA5">Aisa 5</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA6">Aisa 6</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA7">Aisa 7</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA8">Aisa 8</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA9">Aisa 9</option>
        <option rel="VI_TUBES" value="AISA10">Aisa 10</option>
        <!-- VI_PRINTING -->
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG1">KPG1</option>
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG2">KPG2</option>
        <option rel="VI_PRINTING" value="KPG3">KPG3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <span>
      <div class="form-label"><label for="MachineID">Nazwa Maszyny</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="text" name="MachineID" id="Machine_input">  </div>     
    </span>
    <span>           
      <div class="form-label"><label for="DateID">Data wystąpienia problemu</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><input type="date" name="DateID" id="Date_input"></div>   
    </span>
    <span> 
      <div class="form-labelbig"><label for="ProblemID">Opisz problem</label></div>
      <div class="form-smallmessage"><textarea id="text" name="ProblemID" id ="problem_input" rows="10" cols="22"></textarea></div>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="button" value="ZABLOKUJ" id="gobutton">
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, i undestand now :D

Comment: Hiding option isn't supported in all browsers

Comment: True, @charlietfl, but that was not an issue raised by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

change the following code

```
$subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
```

to

```
$subcat.find("option").attr("style", "display:none;");
```